# Bootstrap modal adding linebreak in paragraph

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal

I have a paragraph `<p>...</p>` with a linked image that I want centered on page when NAME is clicked. Default is to upper left in browser.

Research led me to modals. I created a modal that does what I want, but this created another issue.  It creates a line break in the paragraph after the link.

```
<p>
  The Organizational meeting was held Friday evening.
  A special presentation was made by <a href="images/name.jpg" target="_self">NAME</a> of... 
  Also at the meeting, <a href="images/anothername.jpg" target="_self">ANOTHER NAME</a>...
</p>
```

This results in the image opening in the upper left edge of the browser and using the back arrow to return to the page.

This is the code using modal within the paragraph.

```
<p>The Organizational meeting was held Friday evening. A special presentation was made by <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2"><b>NAME</b></a>
    <div id="myModal2" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">            
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">NAME</h4>
                </div>              
                <div class="modal-body">
                <img src="images/name.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer"
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Also at the meeting, 
        **ANOTHERNAME**
        
            
                
                    
                    ANOTHERNAME
                    
                    
                        
                    
                    Close

This gives me an image in a popup window fading into the center of the screen which I can close and be on the current page.  Beautiful!

But in the paragraph, after the NAME, there is a line break or a line spacing larger than specified in CSS. But after the ANOTHERNAME, there is no line break or larger spacing.  Why the difference?  Are the modal divs allowed within the `<p>` tags?  What is the best way to achieve a centered image on the same page when clicked?

Comment: You have two different questions here ("how to center an image" vs "why the weird line breaks").  You're more likely to get help if you focus on just one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.  Issue was caused by (paragraph) tags.  A closed paragraph tag was being added before the

Comment: You have to escape code with backticks (`) if you don't want most of your text to be parsed as html.